# chromedriver.exe Has stopped working

Tags: cucumber, watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My cucumber/ruby/selenium scripts run by starting up a chromebrowser (2.3) session before every test and tearing down after. They have been working for months, but now I have a real problem.

I have 600 scenarios, but when I get to a specific number of scenarios run (251), it bombs out with this message:

Resource temporarily unavailable - chromedriver.exe --port=8602 (Errno::EAGAIN)

If I remove the scenario at which it fails, the issue happens at the next scenario. I tried removing many scenarios but still happens.

I also tried randomizing the ports as I thought that chromedriver connecting to the same port was causing the issue.

I'm stumped!